# Qt: QLineEdit , how to let the text in two lines instead of a long one

Tags: c++, qt

suppose I have a line edit and my window is in fixed size , and I wanted the line edit to display a text , but since the width is not big to see all the text I must drag my mouse left or right to read it all ,

how can I change it so instead of showing the text line this:

End of the width of the line edit:

**text text text text text text *text text text text text***

so look at the italics part , to see the text " the italics one " i must drag the mouse right so I can see it and if I want to get back to the start I drag it to the left.

I want: read it or show it line this:

**text text text text text text** "end of the line here"
"start of the new line:"**text text**

Comment: Seems to me that you should use QTextArea instead of QLineEdit.

Comment: Thanks , I'll try it out hopefully it'll work , I'll reply if it works.

Comment: are you sure it's QTextArea  ? because I haven't found anything about it in qt assistant.

Comment: Sorry, the one I was referring is QTextEdit. Or just Text Edit, if you are looking in the Design section of Qt Creator.

Comment: thank you , used the qtextedit and it works ^^

Comment: @RudLimaverde You should write that as answer. Btw, QPlainTextEdit would probably be enough.